# Ошибка E2099 при вычитании знакового из беззнакового

Tags: delphi, математика, компиляция, delphi-11-alexandria

Есть код в VCL:

```
var
 memall64,memusedal64, mem64new : int64;
 Mtemp : int64;
begin
 memall64 := GlobalMemoryStatusExTotalPhys;
 memusedal64 := GlobalMemoryStatusExAvailPhys;
 mem64new := memall64-memusedal64;
 Mtemp := mem64old - mem64new;  // ошибка при выполнении        
 mem64old := mem64new;
```

который при выполнении дает ошибку E2099. В процессе поиска решения выяснилось

```
 Mtemp : int64;
 MD: single;
 Mtemp := 4002103296 - 4008439808;
 Md := 4002103296 - 4008439808;
```

выдают ошибку. А код

```
Mtemp := 3000000000 - 5000000000;
Md := 4002103296.0 - 4008439808;
```

спокойно проходит. Причем под FMX такой проблемы нет. Чтение аналогичных вопросов решения не дало, кроме того, что может быть компилятор значение сначала пытается впихнуть в 32 бита, а если не влазит то в 64. Причем ему глубоко наплевать на объявленную размерность переменной. И не понятно - связано ли это с директивой оптимизации или нет.

Пока решение - перевел все переменные в single. Но хотелось бы избавится от эти костылей.

Comment: Какие значения у mem64old (объявлена как int64?), memall64 и memusedal64 под отладчиком? Может там функции мусор возвращают, который действительно при операциях в Int64 не вмещается? Ну и про размерность типа Single почитайте.

Comment: Что такое GlobalMemoryStatusExTotalPhys и GlobalMemoryStatusExAvailPhys? Как оно  объявлено?

Comment: @MBo скорее всего, код взят [отсюда](https://delphisources.ru/forum/showpost.php?s=88e382b55efa9da51c0b55c152c3426b&p=149779&postcount=4)

Comment: zed - да взят оттуда  10 лет назад. сенкс за ссылку.  потерял за это время.  значения memall64 и memusedal64 под отладчиком лежат Mtemp := 4002103296 - 4008439808; Монитор прекрасно работал - пока не пришлось выкинуть тормозной и жрущий память TChart и переписывать все под VCL (быстрый. монитор писался для

Comment: оценочной работы алгоритма

Comment: @zed Да, я тоже в единственном месте это нашёл. Подумал - вдруг что в длл-ках спрятано.

Comment: Попробуйте на другой версии компилятора и/или на другой машине. У нас так бывало, что вылезали подобные "фейковые" ошибки на ровном месте.

Comment: чистая система, RAD 10.4 и RAD 11.3 - грабли те-же...

Comment: @Stalkern, эти переменные могут принимать отрицательные значения? Что если - в порядке эксперимента - объявить их как UInt64? Или применить явное преобразование типа в операции вычитания?

Comment: `mem64old` у вас как объявлена? `Mtemp := 4002103296 - 4008439808` - это действие выполняется компилятором, поэтому и ошибка. Попробуйте сделать `Mtemp := Int64(4002103296) - 4008439808` - должно сработать.

Comment: Мдя. Детская болезнь выпуска новых версий. 1 глюк убрали - 3 добавили. Устойчивые ошибки не трогаем.  Alexcvp сенкс за совет. буквально сам докопался минут за 10 до комента. Подробности в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, **вы показываете неверный код и вы не предоставляете минимальный воспроизводимый пример.**

Первый пример:

```
var
 memall64,memusedal64, mem64new : int64;
 Mtemp : int64;
begin
 memall64 := GlobalMemoryStatusExTotalPhys; // значение 4002103296
 memusedal64 := GlobalMemoryStatusExAvailPhys; // значение 4008439808
 mem64new := memall64-memusedal64; // значение -6336512
 Mtemp := mem64old - mem64new;  // mem64old не инициализирован и неизвестного типа
 mem64old := mem64new; // см.ниже
```

Далее вы уточняете, что `mem64old: uint64;`. Ну так тогда у вас ошибка

```
Result := int64(mem64old) - mem64new; // Result неизвестного типа
mem64old := mem64new; // Присваиваете отрицательное значение
```

---

Что касается операции вычитания. Во-первых, компилятор выдает предупреждение:

> [dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(30): W1073 Combining signed type and unsigned 64-bit type - treated as an unsigned type

Компилятор вам честно говорит - операция над знаковым и беззнаковым 64битным будет проведена как беззнаковая. Потому что у компилятора нет в рукаве секретного int128 для избежания возможного переполнения. И если в настройках компилятора включена проверка Overflow Checking, то действительно выкинет такую ошибку (а если не включена, то не выкинет). Далее уже ваша ответственность, отключить в компиляторе Overflow Checking, либо сузить тип до знакового, либо обеспечить неотрицательность. Если вы беззнаковый тип явно преобразуете в знаковый, то эти предупреждение и ошибка уйдут (как и бывшие там отрицательные значения).

С int\uint32 таких проблем нет, т.к. можно "поднять градус" и вычислить в int64, а ответ вписать обратно (оставив только Range Checking, если он включен). С int/uint64 такой возможности "из коробки" нет, т.к. операция уже и так проводится в 64-битных регистрах. Если бы возможность была, то был бы и тип (условно int128), у которого была бы та же проблема при операциях с int\uint128.

---

А то что вы дальше теоретизируете с константами - ну так они вычисляются в момент компиляции, "это другое" и там есть свои правила и ограничения. Например, то о чем вы пишете - значения по умолчанию считаются Cardinal или Integer, если специально не указано, что Int64, например.

---

*В итоге, вы в 1 вопрос замешали 3 ошибки, и похоже, что только чудом, нагородите костылей взаимно-нейтрализующих друг друга.* Делайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример, тогда будет о чём говорить предметно.

Answer (score -2):

Собственно ответ - с int\uint64 никак. с int\uint32 таких проблем нет.
Наследственная болезнь идущая от VCL х32. Или то о чем "книжные теоретики" не имеют понятия. Действительно некорректно привел пример. Поправил. Но проблема так и осталась. хоть константы. хоть переменные. Для наглядности оставил такой вариант т.к. вариант b := ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ВОЗВРАЩАЕМОЕ ИЗ ФУНКЦИИ дает тот-же результат.

Собственно тестовый код

```
var
 a: int64;
 b: uint64;
 c: int64;
begin
 b := 4002103296;
 c := 4008439808;
 a := int64(b) - c;  // work
 memo1.Lines.Add(a.ToString);
 b := $FFFFFFFE;
 c := $FFFFFFFF;
 a := b - c;    // err
 memo1.Lines.Add(a.ToString);
 b := $100000000;
 c := $100000001;
 a := b - c;   // err
 memo1.Lines.Add(a.ToString);
```

если

```
var
a: int64;
 b, c: uint64;
```

то только так

```
a := int64(b) - int64(c);
```

другие варианты (как по книгам) не живут.
Причина
в выражении

А = B +/- C

через B компилятор определяет какой регистр использовать. х32\х64. Но самое главное - ему глубоко наплевать о заявленных размерностях.
И знаковость определяет переменная А. Сначала запихиваем в 32 бит регистр - не лизе то в 64. причем граница определения беззнаковая. то есть если все 3 переменные одного типа - проблем нет. разные ......

```
var
x: int64; 
x := $FFFFFFFF - $FFFFFFFF; // нет ошибки
x := $FFFFFFFе - $FFFFFFFF; // есть
```

опять-же

```
x := uint64($FFFFFFFe) - uint64($FFFFFFFf); // ошибка
```

если

```
x,b,c: uint64;
x := $FFFFFFFF - $FFFFFFFe;
b := $FFFFFFFF;
c := $FFFFFFFe;
x := b - c;
```

все работает

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы всё это выводите из работы компилятора с константами (т.е. то, что вычисляется в момент компиляции, а не в рантайме). Для райнтайма всё несколько иначе.

Comment: Переменные - результат тот-же

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Берем ваш пример, видим предупреждения компилятора на 2 и 3 варианты - `[dcc32 Warning] W1073 Combining signed type and unsigned 64-bit type - treated as an unsigned type`. Компилятор вам честно говорит - операция над знаковым и беззнаковым 64битным будет проведена как беззнаковая. Потому что у компилятора нет в рукаве секретного int128 для избежания возможного переполнения. Далее уже ваша ответственность, отключить в компиляторе Overflow Checking, либо сузить тип до знакового, либо обеспечить неотрицательность (беззнаковость).

Comment: С  int\uint32 таких проблем нет, т.к. можно "поднять градус" и вычислить в int64, а ответ вписать обратно (оставив только Range Checking, если он включен). С int/uint64 такой возможности "из коробки" нет, т.к. операция уже и так проводится в 64-битных регистрах. Если бы возможность была, то был бы и тип (условно int128), у которого была бы та же проблема при операциях с int\uint128.

Comment: Kromster ну что сказать.... 3.14 2.72 ..... Правду говорят на WEB и других "супер интеллектуальных алгоритмах" тупеешь. писал-бы для железа - первым делом задал-бы вопрос - Батенька, а куда собственно вы собираетесь впихивать результат? Ни уж-то в х64 с флагом переноса??? (с характерным таким кортавым говорком) ....